# Get values of all first <td> in a table <tr> except the first using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to return a comma separated list of values for the first td from every tr in a table EXCEPT for the first tr.

In the html table example below i need to return:

41536, 41537

```
<table class="product-options">
<tbody>
<tr class="top-row">
<td>NEW Code</td>
<td>OLD Code</td>
<td>Other Code</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>41536</td>
<td>40227</td>
<td>60544</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>41537</td>
<td>41097</td>
<td>58974</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Right, and how's that going?

Comment: Please go read [ask] - again, if necessary. You should know by now that this is not a site to get code written for you, yet you still give us such a _“I have, I want, I have done nothing so far”_ “question” …

Answer (score 11):

`document.querySelectorAll('table.product-options > tbody > tr:not(:first-child) > td:first-child')`

`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`.

`tr:not(:first-child)` returns all the lines except the first.

`td:first-child` returns the first cell.

Comment: Im trying this but it doesnt work:

function() {
var element = document.querySelectorAll('table.product-options > tr:not(.top-row) > td:first-child');
var id = element.innerText;
return id;
}

Comment: it returns a `NodeList` (some kind of `array`) : you have several elements in it ! you should console.log() it to see what it does looks like :)

Comment: Sorry i dont understand. I know nothing about javascript.

Answer (score 2):

> I suggest you read in on [`CSS Selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

With `document.querySelectorAll` and the correct query it's easy:

We use `:not`  in this case to not select the `tr` we don't want and `:first-child`. for the first td we want

```
table.product-options tr:not(.top-row) > td:first-child
```

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll("table.product-options tr:not(.top-row) > td:first-child");
console.log(list);
```

```html
<table class="product-options">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="top-row">
      <td>NEW Code</td>
      <td>OLD Code</td>
      <td>Other Code</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>41536</td>
      <td>40227</td>
      <td>60544</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>41537</td>
      <td>41097</td>
      <td>58974</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function () {
  let node = 'table.product-options tr:not(.top-row) td:first- 
child'
  let Sku = document.querySelectorAll(node);

  return Array.prototype.map.call(Sku, function(node) {
    return node.textContent.replace(/\s/g, '');
  });
}
```